# Terraform - Azure - azurerm_virtual_machine_extension - multiline Powershell script

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-automation

I am preparing VM deployment, and on VMs I need to run some powershell command lets. I need to install Windows Server role, and initialize new ssd disk. I am working on Azure cloud, Terraform deployment has been tested, works as expected, VM is deployed with all required configuration, but facing some problems during multiline powershell commands. I use terraform resource `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension`, it works when I am trying to install/use one block of code, for example for Windows server role installation. I don't want to use storage account and container and .ps1 script file uploaded to storage container, I need to use inline powershell code. My terraform clode below.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmext" {
  name                 = "vmext"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.app_vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-windowsfeature -name RoleName -IncludeManagementTools; powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Get-Disk | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PartitionStyle -eq 'RAW'} | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'disk2' -Confirm:$false"     
    }
SETTINGS


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmext" {
      name                 = "vmext"
      virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.app_vm.id
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
      type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
      type_handler_version = "1.10"
    
      settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
          "commandToExecute": <<EOF
              powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-windowsfeature -name RoleName -IncludeManagementTools
              powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Get-Disk | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PartitionStyle -eq 'RAW'} | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'disk2' -Confirm:$false"  
              EOF   
        }
    SETTINGS
  }
```

Hope this helps!